# Jquery css selector if no data then apply styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi guys I have a repeating table that has many TR rows that looks like this:

```
<table>     
 <tr class="RowStyle" style="background-color:White;">
         <td>field 1</td>
         <td>field 2</td>
         <td>field 3</td>
         <td class="selector">field 4</td>
         <td>field 5</td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="RowStyle" style="background-color:White;">
         <td>field 1</td>
         <td>field 2</td>
         <td>field 3</td>
         <td class="selector">&nbsp</td>
         <td>field 5</td>
  </tr>
 <tr class="RowStyle" style="background-color:White;">
         <td>field 1</td>
         <td>field 2</td>
         <td>field 3</td>
         <td class="selector">&nbsp</td>
         <td>field 5</td>
  </tr>
```

Jquery:

```
if ( $('.selector').val() = '&nbsp' ) {
    $('.RowStyle').css('background-color', 'red');
 }
```

I need to some how be able to say if text = nothing or &nbsp then change the style of the background, can anyone help me with this - here is [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D774a/1/)...

Comment: (1): `.text()` /  `.html()` instead of `.val()` (2) It is `&nbsp;` not `&nbsp`

Comment: Tried that ... to no avail. if ( $('.selector').text() = '&nbsp;' ) {
    $('.RowStyle').css('background-color', 'red');
}

Comment: yes use text().trim().length == 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$('.selector').each(function(i, element){
    if($(element).text().trim().length == 0)
    {
        $(element).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D774a/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.selector').each(function(){
 if (!$(this).text().trim().length) {
   $(this).closest('.RowStyle').css('background-color', 'red');
}});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D774a/9/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$('.selector').filter(function(){ 
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "" 
}).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D774a/5/)

Comment: @RohitAzad why..? Am i missing anything..?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if ( !$('.selector').text().length || $('.selector').html() == '&nbsp' ) {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', 'red');
 }
```